# Buscar otro atributo que no sea .val() en un input.select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito entrar en el `if` buscando el atributo `code` de la opción seleccionada

Tengo un `input.select` con varias opciones, las cuales tienen el atributo `value` y `code`

```js
$('#PRODUCT_ECONOMIC').change(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('code') == "PRIOBJ"){
    console.log("Si");
  }
  else {
    console.log("No");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="PRODUCT_ECONOMIC" class="multiselect"> 
  <option value="362" code="MEJACT">Mejorar el Actual</option> 
  <option value="1144" code="PRIEST">Precio Estimado</option> 
  <option value="360" code="PRIOBJ">Precio Objetivo</option> 
  <option value="361" code="NPRIOBJ">Sin Precio Objetivo</option> 
</select>
```

Ya se que, lo que está buscando, es el atributo `code` del mismo `select`, y no de la opción seleccionada

Obviamente, si cambio `.attr()` por `.val()` funciona perfectamente, pero necesito que sea por el atributo `code`

Comment: Como añadido, tu problema es que `$(this)` hace referencia al `select` y no al `option` seleccionado, para compararlo lo puedes hacer como te indica @phpMyGuel en su respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A través de la pseudo-clase `selected` podemos saber si un elemento se encuentra seleccionado o no.

Sabiendo eso podemos seleccionar el `<option>` que tenga `:selected`.

```js
$('#PRODUCT_ECONOMIC').change(function(){
  if ($(this).find('option:selected').attr('code') == "PRIOBJ"){
    console.log("Si");
  }
  else {
    console.log("No");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="PRODUCT_ECONOMIC" class="multiselect"> 
  <option value="362" code="MEJACT">Mejorar el Actual</option> 
  <option value="1144" code="PRIEST">Precio Estimado</option> 
  <option value="360" code="PRIOBJ">Precio Objetivo</option> 
  <option value="361" code="NPRIOBJ">Sin Precio Objetivo</option> 
</select>
```